# Call table valued function using Jpa specification

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have 2 queries, one is doing a presearch using contains and the second one uses the result from the first one, using JPA Specification.

And I need to keep only one query, since i couldnt do cb.function(CONTAINS,...) I created a table valued function that makes this contains in SQL Server.

The issue now is that I cannot call this table valued function from JPA Specification:

```java
    public static Specification<CreditApplication> tryCustomFunction(String first, String last) {
        return (Root<CreditApplication> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {
            List<Predicate> andPredicates = new ArrayList<>();

            andPredicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(CreditApplication_.firstAndLastName),
                    cb.function("Z001.getApplicationsByFirstAndLastName", String.class, cb.literal(first), cb.literal(last))));

            return cb.and(andPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
        };

    }
```

It says:

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot
> find either column "Z001" or the user-defined function or aggregate
> "Z001.getApplicationsByFirstAndLastName", or the name is ambiguous.

Scalar functions works well with this notation but this type of functions throws me this error.

I tried defining it as a store procedure and doesnt work also.

I'm using hibernate-core 5.3.7 and Spring data jpa 2.1.3.

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: It's hard to help when you show no code at all or stack traces.

Comment: You're right, I've now put the code im using and the hibernate and jpa versions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you really are using a table valued function, you have to understand that it can only be used in the from clause. There is no support for table valued functions in Hibernate.

As far as I understood, you don't even need table valued functions. You mentioned you tried to use the `CONTAINS` function. What did you try? What didn't work?

I think the following should work just fine:

```
public static Specification<CreditApplication> tryCustomFunction(String first, String last) {
    return (Root<CreditApplication> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {
        List<Predicate> andPredicates = new ArrayList<>();

        andPredicates.add(cb.isTrue(cb.function("CONTAINS", Boolean.class, root.get(CreditApplication_.firstAndLastName), cb.literal(first + " OR " + last))));

        return cb.and(andPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    };

}
```

Comment: Hi
I've tried that and it says:

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '='.

The sql created is ending in:

...
WHERE CONTAINS (
  creditappl0_.APPS41,
  'test'
  ) = 1

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that a function must return a scalar value for Hibernate, but `CONTAINS` is a predicate and SQL server does not support booleans... You could try creating a function that does `CASE WHEN CONTAINS(arg1, arg2,...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` and use that function instead.